# Magento 2.4 Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Adapter\Mysql\Filter\AliasResolver does not exist

Tags: magento2, upgrade, class, magento2.4

After upgrading to magento 2.4 from 2.3.5-p1 and running setup:di:compile, the following error occurs:

```
In ClassReader.php line 43:

  Class Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Adapter\Mysql\Filter\AliasResolver does not exist


In ClassReader.php line 36:

  Class Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Adapter\Mysql\Filter\AliasResolver does not exist
```

To track down the issue, I tried `php bin/magento dev:di:info "Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Adapter\Mysql\Filter\AliasResolver"` and got the following:

```
DI configuration for the class Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Adapter\Mysql\Filter\AliasResolver in the GLOBAL area

Preference: Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Adapter\Mysql\Filter\AliasResolver

Constructor Parameters:

In ClassReader.php line 26:

  Class Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Adapter\Mysql\Filter\AliasResolver does not exist


dev:di:info  <class>
```

I disabled all third party modules, and I have elasticsearch enabled. Not sure what else i can do besides trying a clean install of Magento 2.4. Is there anything further I can do to troubleshoot this?

Comment: AliasResolver is not exists in 2.4. Can you check where it used in your codebase? Also can you cleanup cache at fierst

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I cleaned cache multiple times but no luck. I did see that AliasResolver was removed in 2.4, so it is strange that this error is occurring. To check the codebase as you stated, I need to check that Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Adapter\Mysql\Filter\AliasResolver does not exist within a file in the vendor directory, is that correct?

Comment: Actually you need to find usage of these class. Looks like it present in some of di.xml files